# Programmatic Web Browsing via a Proxy

Tags: python, proxy

I am currently writing a Python script which basically visits different websites and reads some data from those websites.  However, there is a complexity to it. I am based in country A, but the data on that website is only available in country B.  This means that I need a script which connects to a proxy server in country B and only then begins to browse programmatically.

So far I have written the script for browsing using the mechanize module.  However, I am totally unsure about how to make it run via a proxy.

EDIT: The connection to the proxy has a username and a password.

Does anyone have any idea of how to do this?

Comment: I forgot to add: what if the proxy has a password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In mechanize do something like this:

```
browser = mechanize.Browser()
browser.set_proxies({"http": "111.11.11.11"})
response = browser.open("http://google.com")
```

then set it to the proxy you want the browser to connect too

or you can change the proxy for a certain request like this:

```
req = mechanize.Request("http://www.google.com")
req.set_proxy("localhost:8888","http")
mechanize.urlopen(req)
```

use a proxy with a password:

```
# Proxy and user/password
br.set_proxies({"http": "joe:password@myproxy.example.com:3128"})

# Proxy
br.set_proxies({"http": "myproxy.example.com:3128"})
# Proxy password
br.add_proxy_password("joe", "password")
```

Comment: Thank you Christian! I forgot to add: what if the proxy has a password? In my case I use a browser embedded tool that is called "FoxyProxy" which requires a username and a password.

Comment: Thank you so much Christian! :) I am going to check this shortly and let you know if it works!